# Spring boot testcontainers configured via properties to use r2dbc throws java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver

Tags: spring-boot-testcontainers

This is my application-it.yml file:

```
spring:
  r2dbc:
    url: r2dbc:tc:mysql:///warehouse-db?TC_IMAGE_TAG=latest
```

Here are my dependencies from pom.xml:

```
<dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-r2dbc</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-webflux</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
          <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
          <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.asyncer</groupId>
            <artifactId>r2dbc-mysql</artifactId>
        </dependency>

 <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-testcontainers</artifactId>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.projectreactor</groupId>
            <artifactId>reactor-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.testcontainers</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.testcontainers</groupId>
            <artifactId>testcontainers</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.testcontainers</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.testcontainers</groupId>
            <artifactId>r2dbc</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

This is my test class:

```
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
@ActiveProfiles(profiles = "it")
@Testcontainers
@TestInstance(Lifecycle.PER_CLASS)
@Import(SchemaCreatorConfig.class)
public class WarehouseControllerIT{

    @Autowired
    private WebTestClient client;
    
    @Test
    void givenInvalidWarehouseDTO_whenCreateWarehouse_thenReturnBadRequest() {
        WarehouseDTO dto = new WarehouseDTO();
        dto.setCountry("Spain9");
        dto.setState("Madrid");
        dto.setCity("Madrid");
        dto.setStreetNameAndNo("stree name and num");
        dto.setName("es-madrid");
        client.post().uri("/api/warehouse").body(Mono.just(dto),WarehouseDTO.class).exchange()
            .expectStatus().isBadRequest();
    }
}
```

I think I have configured the r2dbc url correctly and included the neccessary dependencies and I can not figure out what I am missing here since I already have included aync mysql driver. Why is it trwoing that exception?